# Não consigo fazer conexão com Banco de Dados no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Boa noite,

Não estou conseguindo fazer conexão com o banco de dados para criar as tabelas da pasta Models no .NET. Quando tento fazer as Migrations retorna este erro:

"Não foi possível executar porque o comando ou o arquivo especificado não foi encontrado.
Possíveis motivos para isso incluem:

Você digitou incorretamente um comando de dotnet interno. Você pretendia executar um programa .NET, mas dotnet-ef não existe. Você pretendia executar uma ferramenta global, mas não foi possível encontrar um executável com prefixo de dotnet com esse nome no CAMINHO."

O comando que utilizei para fazer as migrations foi este: **dotnet ef migrations add**

Já fiz a configuração do DbContext desta forma:

`````
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APIVirtualCard.Data
{
    public class VCContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Email> Emails { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=myDb;trusted_connection=true;");
        }
    }
}````
`````

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o comando "ef" do dotnet não foi encontrado, ou por não ter sido instalado, ou por não estar no seu PATH.

Para instalar faça: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`

Para colocar no PATH, de modo que seja encontrado e possa ser utilizado de qualquer lugar:

- No Windows: vá em editar variáveis de ambiente e adicione `%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools` (ou o local onde as ferramentas do dotnet são instaladas no seu sistema) à variável `PATH`.
- No Linux: Adicione uma linha na configuração do shell `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools/"`
- No MacOS: Adicione uma linha na configuração do shell `set path = ($path $HOME/.dotnet/tools/)`

ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862089/cannot-find-command-dotnet-ef

Depois disso, `dotnet ef migrations add NomeDescritivoDaSuaMigracao` deve gerar a sua migração e um snapshot no modelo, deixando tudo certo para um subsequente `dotnet ef database update`